# Do Japanese have a different pelvis position than Europeans?

Tags: human-anatomy

I was watching a show that made the claim that European women's pelvis is tilted more forward compared to Japanese women's which places their butts higher up.

Is this information accurate?

Comment: It's probably best to not assume that anatomy in anime is accurate.

Comment: While the context of the question is "un-scientific", the question itself is neither off-topic nor opinion-based. The question is clearly asking about anatomy of human pelvises which can easily be answered scientifically. Those that are close-voting need to check yourselves and review what constitutes "off-topic" and "opinion-based".

Comment: I removed where I heard the claim from.

Comment: Which makes your claims even more "opinion based".

Comment: @Chris, it's not "my" claim and how is it even opinion-based? I heard something from a television show and I want to know if there are any studies to support the statement made by the source. This is not an opinion based question because studies can prove whether or not there are differences in pelvic positioning between populations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this study](http://thejns.org/doi/abs/10.3171/2012.2.SPINE11755) there are significant pelvic position differences between Caucasian and Asian populations. However the biggest difference is lumbar lordosis (the curve at the small of the back) where Caucasians have almost 10 degrees more curve. The study doesn't explicitly say it but that would suggest Caucasians butts are higher.

Comment: Well well well what do you know! They were right!